# Populate NSTableView with struct

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I´m trying to populate a `NSTableView` with a struct. The struct is getting it's data from Firebase. I have tried to replicate the way I would do it in `iOS` but I'm not quite there yet.

`var orders = [OrderModel]()`

```
struct OrderModel {
    var order: String!
    var name: String?
    var adress: String?
    var email: String?
}
```

**Read from Firebase:**

```
ref?.child("orders").observe( .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
            
            let newData = OrderModel(order: dict["order"] as? String, name: dict["name"] as? String, adress: dict["adress"] as? String, email: dict["email"] as? String
            
            self.orders.append(newData)
            })
```

**Populate the `NSTableView`:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
            guard let userCell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "ordersCell"), owner: self) as? OrdersTableViewCell else { return nil }
        
        //the object
        let order: OrderModel
        
        //getting the object of selected position
        order = orders[row] //Error index out of range
        
        userCell.orderLabel.stringValue = order.order ?? "Error getting order"
        userCell.nameLabel.stringValue = order.name ?? "Error getting name"
        userCell.adressLabel.stringValue = order.adress ?? "Error getting address"
         return userCell
        }
```

I don't know if the only problem here is this line:

> order = orders[row] //Error index out of range

But that is where I'm at now.

Comment: Please add your `NSTableViewDataSource` code. How do you update the table view when `self.orders` changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike in iOS in macOS there is a more sophisticated way to populate a table view: Cocoa Bindings. As you are using only one cell view for all data this is preferable.

- First make your struct a class inheriting from `NSObject`

  ```
    @objcMembers
    class OrderModel : NSObject {
        dynamic var order: String?
        dynamic var name: String?
        dynamic var adress: String?
        dynamic var email: String?

        init(order : String?, name : String?, adress : String?, email : String?) {
            self.order = order
            self.name = name
            self.adress = adress
            self.email = email
        }
    }
  ```
- Delete the entire method `tableView: viewFor: row:`
- Adopt `NSTableViewDataSource` and `NSTableViewDelegate` in the view controller
- Implement these two methods in the view controller

  ```
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int
    {
        return orders.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        return orders[row]
    }
  ```
- Select the storyboard or xib in the project navigator
- Remove the identifier of the table cell view
- Select the table view (not the scroll view!), press <kbd>⌥⌘7</kbd> to open the Connections Inspector and connect (control-drag) `dataSource` and `delegate` to the view controller
- Select the ***Order*** text field in the table cell view. Make sure it **is** the text field.
- Press <kbd>⌥⌘8</kbd> to open the Bindings Inspector
- Click on the disclosure triangle next to `Value`
- Check `Bind To` -> `Table Cell View`
- In *Model Key Path* enter `objectValue.order`
- Do the same in the other text fields (replace `order` with the other properties respectively)
- In the view controller after receiving the data from Firebase reload the table view inside the closure on the main thread

  ```
  self.orders.append(newData)
  DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
  ```

Comment: I just deleted my comment. I found the error causing the crash. I had connected the NSTableView to the ViewController. It's not crashing now. However, with the new class OrderModel, it's not downloading correctly from Firebase. Is this still the right way to get data from Firebase: `let newData = OrderModel(order: dict["order"] as? String, ...(and so on)`

Comment: I’m not familiar with Firebase, sorry. Create some dummy objects to prove at least if the table view works.

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` I did: `let data = OrderModel(order: "Test order", name: "Peter Parker", adress: "Kings Road", email: "peter@parker.com)` and orders.append(data)` But that won't work either. Have I completely lost my train of thought??

Comment: As mentioned in the answer you have to reload the table view after appending objects.

Comment: Yes, but when I ` print("Data: \(data)")` from my comment above (in `viewDidLoad`), It prints: `Data: <MyProject.OrderModel: 0x600002916b50>` so it seems that the OrderModel is not populating?

Comment: No, the printout is fine, you have to call `self.tableView.reloadData()`